# Parse Ember fixture data and make available to nested view

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to feed fixture data to both a handlebars template and a nested view. With my current setup, the data reaches my handlebars template just fine, but not the view. I suspect I am missing some basic piece of the [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js) puzzle. Would someone please advise me?

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063741/rendering-coordinates-on-leaflet-map-view-using-ajax-in-ember) about a setup that is similar but uses ajax instead of fixture data, but have further simplified my setup in the hopes of getting some direction.

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        {{outlet}}
      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
        {{view App.MapView id="map" contentBinding="this"}}
          <div id="blog">
            <ul>
                {{#each}}
                    <li>{{title}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
          </div>
      </script>

      <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
      <script src="js/libs/ember-1.5.0.js"></script>
      <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
      <script src="js/libs/leaflet-src.js"></script>  
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>


    </body>
    </html>

    window.App = Ember.Application.create();

    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

    App.Router.map(function() {
      this.resource('index', { path: '/' });
    });


    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function () {
        return this.store.find('storyPrev');
      }
    });


    App.StoryPrev = DS.Model.extend({
      title: DS.attr('string')
    });

    App.StoryPrev.FIXTURES = [
     {
       id: 1,
       title: 'You Better Believe This!',
       coordinates: [-73.989321, 40.6778]
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       title: 'Holy Crap, Unreal!',
       coordinates: [-73.989321, 40.6779]
     },
     {
       id: 3,
       title: 'Big Bucks Made E-Z!',
       coordinates: [-73.989321, 40.6780]
     }
    ];

    App.MapView = Ember.View.extend({
        didInsertElement: function () {
            var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false}).setView([40.685259, -73.977664], 14);
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/[redacted key]/[redacted id]/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
            L.marker([40.685259, -73.977664]).addTo(map);  


           console.log(this.get('content'));
    //THIS IS WHERE I GET STUCK



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is backed by a controller, so you would do `this.get('controller')` to get the controller which is backed by your collection which if you wanted to get the collection (which isn't necessary since you can iterate the controller) you could do `this.get('controller.model')`.

```
var controller = this.get('controller');
controller.forEach(function(item){
   console.log(item.get('title'));
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/373/edit

Comment: What syntax would I use to drill down to a specific 'title', rather than an array of 'titles', please?